# ManyToMany with one side Not Null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

can i define in NHibernate a many-to-many relationship with one side not null?
My example classes are:

```
public interface IUser
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   IList<IGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

public interface IGroup
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   IList<IUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUser
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<IGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group : IGroup
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<IUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
   public UserMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SequenceIdentity();
      Map(x => x.Name).Not.Null();
      HasManyToMany<Group>(x => x.Groups).Cascade.All();
   }
}

public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
   public GroupMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SequenceIdentity();
      Map(x => x.Name).Not.Null();
      HasManyToMany<User>(x => x.Users).Cascade.All();
   }
}
```

With this settings, i can add a user without a group (Groups == null or empty) and a group without users (Users == null or empty). But what i want to is:
   forbid to add a user without a group
   allow to add a group without a user

I know about Reference on OneToMany relationships, but i don't know how to define Not.Null() on ManyToMany releationships and i have no doubt how to define this just for one side.

Is it possible at all or do i have to check this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

No, mappings will not allow you to constrain your model for ensuring an entity always has at least one element in a collection it owns (be it a many-to-many or a one-to-many).

So even swapping your many-to-many for two one-to-many with an intermediate associating entity would not help. Only a many-to-one or a one-to-one can require the other end to be not null. And here this applies to a single related entity, not to a collection of related entities.

If that makes sens, you may instead map a single "main group" as a many-to-one on your user, and mandates this main group to be mandatory. This will of course add a foreign key column on your user toward the main group.

Otherwise yes, you have to check that rule by code